# Recursive permutation in Java generating wrong result

Tags: java, recursion, permutation

The problem is to generate lexicographic permutations.

At first, my code was like this:

```
public class Problem24 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    permutation("","123");
}

public static void permutation(String prefix, String numbers) {
    if (numbers.length() == 0) {
        System.out.println(prefix);
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length(); i++) {
            prefix = prefix + numbers.charAt(i);
            permutation(prefix,numbers.substring(0, i)+numbers.substring(i+1));
        }
    }

}
}
```

The result:

```
123
1232
1213
12131
12312
123121
```

When I changed this two lines from

```
prefix = prefix + numbers.charAt(i);
permutation(prefix,numbers.substring(0, i)+numbers.substring(i+1));
```

to:

```
permutation(prefix + numbers.charAt(i),numbers.substring(0, i)+numbers.substring(i+1));
```

The result becomes right.

This two ways seems equivalent to me. Can someone explain what's different and why the first one would generate wrong result.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following one keep adding changes to the `prefix` between each iteration in for-loop

```
prefix = prefix + numbers.charAt(i);
permutation(prefix,numbers.substring(0, i)+numbers.substring(i+1));
```

while this one only pass the changes on `prefix` to the next level of invocation, it match the purpose of this recursive function well

```
permutation(prefix + numbers.charAt(i),numbers.substring(0, i)+numbers.substring(i+1));
```

To visualize the recursive call under each level:

(Correct version)

```
Level:  1  |   2  |   3
        -- | ---- |  ---
prefix  1  |  12  |  123
           |  13  |  132
        2  |  21  |  213
           |  23  |  231
        3  |  31  |  312
           |  32  |  321
```

(Wrong version)

```
Level:   1  |   2    |   3
        --- | ------ | -----
prefix   1  |  12    |  123
            |  123   |  1232
        12  |  121   |  1213
            |  1213  |  12131
       123  |  1231  |  12312
            |  12312 |  123121
```

Comment: Thanks, so the value passed is indeed the same, but I forgot I was using the value of `prefix` in the for-loop.

Comment: @AntonZ ya, hope the updated table looks clear to you for why the error result looks like that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when the recursion occur, when the values are popped from the stack, when you do:

```
prefix = prefix + numbers.charAt(i);
```

The changes will occur on each level of the call hierarchy. But when you do:

```
permutation(prefix + numbers.charAt(i),numbers.substring(0, i)+numbers.substring(i+1));
```

You're only performing `prefix + numbers.charAt(i)` once.